# UIImageView Class problem

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have taken an Imageview class and iam adding image into that with code:
 TileImageView *tileImageView = [[Tile alloc] initWithImage:tileImage];

and adding into view like this:[self.view insertSubview:tileImageView atIndex:0];

So how to remove the Imageview class and alloc new image to that view

Comment: Didn't even notice that. Pretty sad: 22 questions asked, most of them with answers, and zero accepted answers

Comment: Wow ive never seen that before!

Answer (score 2):

There's a tag property in the UIView class which you can use to retrieve the view later.

```
titleImageView.tag = 1;

[self.view addSubview:titleImageView];

// later:

titleImageView = [self.view viewWithTag:1];
titleImage.view.image = otherImage;
```

Or you can save the reference to the image view in an instance variable.